# Guidance creating a WebAPI for a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, webapi

I would like some guidance/tips on the best way to approach this challenge.

In my case the context is around having to manage multiple variants of datasources and connections but for sake of simplicity I used the concept of a car.

I want to call a WebAPI but provide it with an implementation of a base class.

In the arguments for the API call (e.g. modelbinder) I want to provide a generic type, that implements the ICar interface or at least, is derived from the abstract Car class. But as the payload doesn't provide any clues on the brand of the car, we have no way of deserializing it either being a Ford or a Tesla.

Additionally I am not allowed to use interfaces or abstract types and need to provide a concrete class. By providing Car as a class, it doesn't automatically cast it to being a Ford or a Tesla.

Unfortunately as I was progressing I got myself stuck and probably doing it the wrong way. I hope someone can help me provide some pointers in the right direction.

**Interface**

```
namespace MyApp.Interface
{
    public interface IEntity
    {
        string Id { get; set; }
    }
    
    public interface ICar : IEntity
    {
        string Brand { get; set; }     
        bool Gasoline {get;set;}
        bool Electric {get;set;}
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace MyApp.Model
{
    public class BaseModel : IEntity
    {
            public string Id { get; set; }
    }
       
    public abstract class Car : BaseModel, ICar
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public bool Gasoline { get; set; }
        public bool Electric {get; set;}
    }

    public class Ford : Car
    {
        // we assume this car uses gasoline
    }
    public class Tesla : Car
    {
        // we assume this car uses electricity
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class BaseViewModel
    {
        public BaseViewModel(){}
        public BaseViewModel(string id)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                Id = id;
            }
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class BaseViewModel<TModel> : BaseViewModel where TModel : IEntity, new()
    {
        protected BaseViewModel(){}
        protected BaseViewModel(string id) : base(id)
        {

        }
        public TModel ToModel()
        {
            var model = new TModel();
            ToModel(model);
            return model;
        }

        public abstract void ToModel(TModel model);
        
    }
    
    public class CarViewModels
    {
        public class BaseCar : BaseViewModel<Car>
        {
            public string Brand { get; set; }
            public bool Gasoline { get; set; }
            public bool Electric {get; set;}

            public BaseCar() : base() { }
            public BaseCar(Car model) : base(model.Id)
            {
                Brand = model.Brand;
            }
            public override void ToModel(Car model)
            {
                model.Id = Id;
                model.Brand = Name;
            }
        }

        public class Ford : BaseCar
        {
            // Ford specifics

            public Ford() : base() { }
            public Ford(ICar model) : base(model) { }
        }
        public class Tesla : BaseCar
        {
            // Ford specifics

            public Ford() : base() { }
            public Ford(ICar model) : base(model) { }
        }
    }
}
```

**API**

```
namespace MyApp.Api
{
    public class CarController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly CarService _carService;

        public CarController() { }
        public CarController(IAsyncDocumentSession documentSession,
                        SchemaService schemaService) : base(documentSession)
        {
            _schemaService = schemaService;
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]CarViewModels model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            try
            {
                
                // persist
                var entity = model.ToModel();
                await _documentSession.StoreAsync(entity);

                // recharge (e.g. fill up with gas or electricity based on type of car)             
                var result = await _carService.DoSomething(entity.Id);
                
                return Ok(entity);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return InternalServerError(ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You might want o lookup json polymorphism or 'TypeNameHandling'. The idea is to include the typename of the actual type in the serialized json. So it can then be used to construct the correct type when deserializing.

Comment: Note that your ViewModel classes are just weird. `CarViewModels` is a class, but is used as a namespace. `CarViewModels.Tesla` have Ford as constructor name, and takes a `ICar`, while the base class takes a `Car`. `ToModel` does not create a new model object, but rather applies properties, etc. I would suggest to either just serialize the model classes directly, or to introduce a parallel `CarDTO` object hierarchy for serialization.

Comment: Correct; originally I have separated viewmodels for Create, Edit, Detail, etc. requiring different input and then it makes more sense but in this case it was a leftover trying to provide demo code.

Comment: I actually solved this one by a combination of dynamically instantiating the required derived implementation; indeed by looking into a specific property on the implementation. 

I will probably do something similar to link the correct model with the correct factory instantation.